# Перегрузка оператора "<" для ключа-структуры в std::map

Tags: c++, stl, перегрузка-операторов

Имеется:

```
struct coordinate
{
    int pos_x, pos_y;
    coordinate(int, int);
}
```

А также пользовательский класс `Class`.

Вопрос: как нужно перегрузить

```
bool operator < ();
```

для `coordinate`, чтобы можно было создать `std::map<coordinate, Class> Map;`?

Огромное спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А как вы хотите сравнивать? вот, скажем, (2,5) больше или меньше (5,2)?

Например, если сравнивать сначала по x, а при равенстве координаты x - по y, то достаточно типа такого:

```
bool operator<(const coordinate&a,
               const coordinate&b)
{
    if (a.pos_x == b.pos.x) return a.pos_y < b.pos_y;
    return a.pos_x < b.pos.x;
}
```

или

```
bool operator<(const coordinate&a,
               const coordinate&b)
{
    return std::tie(a.pos_x,a.pos_y) < std::tie(b.pos_x,b.pos_y);
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: думаю логичнее всего сравнивать координаты больше-меньше по 2 и 4 четвертям.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Моя любимая фраза - "*Без точного ТЗ результат ХЗ*". Я привел вариант для иллюстрации, не более того.

Comment: а ещё можно в структуру coordinates добавить метод: `bool operator<(const coordiantes& other) const{...}`

Comment: Плюсик за `tie`. :)